# Avoid Latex float table being placed at the end of the document?

Tags: latex

In latex, when I place a table with 'htb' attribute they are placed at the end of the document. If I want them to be placed in the place as they are declared in the code, how could I do? I've try the float package and the attribute 'H' but finally all the tables are not shown.
The code is as below

```
\documentclass[11pt,conference,letterpaper,doublecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{flushend}

\begin{table*}[htb]
\caption{caption}
\label{tab:tab1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

The result is that all tables are placed at the end of the document in a new page. Could you help me out? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you not allowing `p`? If you are not allowing a float that is big enough to need its own page to get its own page, it (and all following tables) will get pushed towards the end of the document.

Comment: After I use the "htbp" attribute, they are still pushed toward the end of the document.